# Installing Viper tools for ENVI?

Tags: installation, envi

How can I install the VIPER TOOLS plug-in (for Multiple Endmember Spectral Mixture Analysis) in ENVI 5.1 (and later ENVI versions)?

I have failed to complete the process following the VIPER TOOLS 1.5 user manual that focuses on ENVI 4.2.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: Are those tools supported at that version of ENVI?

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error? What installation method did you use? Are you trying to use the tool in ENVI 5.1 Classic or the new interface? Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/190147/edit) your question to provide this information.

Comment: I have tried everything to install the viper tool add-on. Tried the installation method given in the user manual and also the method suggested above. failed each time. Can anyone tell me what could be wrong? besides the links given above aren't functional anymore either.

Comment: What were the precise and detailed steps that you performed when trying to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for ENVI 5.3 (paths will be slightly different for ENVI 5.1).

*Note: I have tested that the tool appears in the ENVI Menu and can be started. I have no idea whether it actually runs correctly.*

1. Download [vipertools_binary_v1.5.zip](http://www.vipertools.org/sites/vipertools/files/binary/vipertools_binary_v1.5.zip) (not the installer)
2. Create folder "viper" in C:\Program Files\Exelis\ENVI53\classic\save_add
3. Extract zip and copy both .sav files to C:\Program Files\Exelis\ENVI53\classic\save_add\viper
4. Download [vipertools_source_v1.5.zip](http://www.vipertools.org/sites/vipertools/files/source/vipertools_source_v1.5.zip)
5. Extract zip and copy men_vipertools.pro to C:\Program Files\Exelis\ENVI53\classic\save_add\viper
6. Start ENVI Classic, not ENVI.
7. Viper tools is under the Spectral menu.

[image]

Comment: ENVI will let you install multiple versions on a computer so you should be able to install and run 4.7 or 4.8 if the classic version of 5.3 doesn't work.

Comment: Step 3 was the missing bit. I will try this and hope that it works.

Comment: Do you know a valid link to download viper? Thank you,

Comment: It's no longer available, unless you can find someone with a copy of the add on.

Answer (score 1):

ENVI will let you install multiple versions on a computer so you should be able to install and run 4.7 or 4.8 if the classic version of 5.3 doesn't work.